# Where is log message "document saving on resign active finished" coming from?

Tags: swiftui, uidocument

In my iOS SwiftUI app, I have a navigation view that lists links to several open Objective-C UIDocuments. While debugging my SwiftUI app in XCode, When I switch to another app, I get a log message in the console about "[UIDocumentLog] document saving on resign active finished" for each open document. Where is this log message coming from?  Is there a way to turn it off?  Does this indicate something amiss with my code?

Answer (score 0):

`UIDocument` supports autosaving. Apple's documentation on `UIDocument` says

> Change Tracking
>
> To enable the autosaving feature of UIDocument, you must notify it
>   when users make changes to a document. UIDocument periodically checks
>   whether the hasUnsavedChanges method returns YES; if it does, it
>   initiates the save operation for the document.

So as your app goes into the background, `UIDocument` seems to be doing a check to see if autosaving is required.

I see this message on documents opened *read-only*. I can also confirm that no changes occur to such files. So I interpret this message as an indication that a check is being made (and optionally autosaving).

So the message is harmless, and unfortunately I don't think you can turn it off.